# I have an Excel file with pivot tables accessing external data (a separate Excel file). Where do I put this external data file?

Tags: excel, external-data, pivot-tables

I have an Excel file containing both VBA macros, and pivot tables which access data from an external source (another Excel file).

I've been asked to share this dashboard via SharePoint.  As it contains Macros I know I need SharePoint to open the full Excel program on user's machines rather than the Webapp.  That works fine and the macros work fine.

However, where do I need to save the Excel file containing the external data?  Most users won't have rights to the folder where its currently kept.  So where do I put this files so all users can access the data used by the pivot tables?

Thanks

Matt